# AttributeError: type object 'WebDriver' has no attribute 'find_elements_by_link_text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, selenium-chromedriver, attributeerror

**What is the updated way to write find elements by link text?**
long story longer... I have about 4000 links on various pages of a website to click. (If I can automate this I can use it as a template for the rest of the common link texts as well on other pages)

specifically, I need to know where I went wrong? Been at this for some time now. I decided to throw in the towel for the night but I cannot find a workaround that is liked my mac terminal/visual studio/ pylance. they all love to yell lol. anyway, I am on a MacBook Pro Laptop and I'd really appreciate some help!

````
import webbrowser
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome

# Not an actual link for public purposes
URL = "https://banfaouf.com/lfmamdofpisao"
webbrowser.open(URL)

# Find all links that contain specific text (e.g., 'Click Me' in this example)
links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Download File')


# Add a time delay (in seconds) between clicks
time_delay_between_clicks = 2  # Adjust this value as needed (e.g., 2 seconds)

# Click each link with a time delay between clicks
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(time_delay_between_clicks)```
````

(This is my first post on this platform!) Idk if this makes any difference but among factors to consider:
I' using:
MacBook Pro (all up to date) and Mac Terminal is also in working order
Latest Version of Python

- Selenium
- VS Code
- chrome driver

have been installed

Answer (score 0):

what is the version of your selenium,Assuming latest version
*find_elements_by_link_text has been abolish from `selenium 4.3.0`*

`webbrowser module` is part of python standard library. if you use it, you will not be able to use selenium, make use of `webdriver` instead
these two line of code should change from

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Download File')
webbrowser.open(URL)
```

to

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, "Download File")
driver.get(URL)
```

and makes sure to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

the full code should be this

```
import webbrowser
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
##location of google chrome example
options.binary_location = r"C:\\Users\\GoogleChrome.exe"
##chrome driver location example
service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\python\\chromedriver\\ChromeDriver 106.0.5249.61\\chromedriver.exe')
caps = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options,desired_capabilities=caps)
# Not an actual link for public purposes
URL = "https://banfaouf.com/lfmamdofpisao"
driver.get(URL)

# Find all links that contain specific text (e.g., 'Click Me' in this example)
links = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Download File')


# Add a time delay (in seconds) between clicks
time_delay_between_clicks = 2  # Adjust this value as needed (e.g., 2 seconds)

# Click each link with a time delay between clicks
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(time_delay_between_clicks)
```

Comment: I should remove the first line of code as well, correct?
 import webbrowser

Comment: and it is not liking executable_path it keeps saying "service is undefined"

Comment: and I am using the latest version of selenium, correct

Comment: Yes you can comment or remove first line

Comment: No, I think it's because the link is not visible until the mouse cursor waives over each item. Then the link appears.